# How to structure functional testing for a Django project

Tags: django, testing, functional-testing, splinter

I would like to create functional tests to cover my Django project.  It is a multipage form that accepts input on each page.  The input on previous pages changes the content/options for the current pages.  The testing is currently set up with Splinter and PhantomJS.  I see two main ways to set this up.

*For each page, create an instance of that page using stored data and point Splinter towards that.*

**Benefits**

- Allows random access testing of any page in the app
- Can reuse unit test definitions to populate these synthetic pages

**Downsides**

- Needs some kind of back end to be set up that Splinter can point to (At this point I have no idea how this would work, but it seems time consuming)

*Structure the testing so that it is done in order, with the test content of page 1 passed to page 2*

**Benefits**

- Seems like it should just work out of the box

**Downsides**

- Does not allow the tests to be run in an arbitrary order/only one at a time
- Would probably take longer to run
- Errors on earlier pages will affect later pages

I've found many tutorials on how to do functional testing on a small scale (individual pages/features/etc.) but I'm trying to figure out if there is an accepted way or best practice on how to structure it over a large project.  Is it one of these? Something else that I've missed?

Answer (score 1):

What I was looking for was fixtures (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata).  Things just get way too complex if you're trying to pass browser state between a whole project worth of tests.  Easy to grab the DB state, easy to load in.